# column Calculation if column > 1in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, calculated-columns

hi i am trying to calculate a value of certain columns together and depending if a column is a certain value  for instance

```
if lens.qty > 1 then  (CASE LENS.LNS_PROGTYPE  --DESIGN pOINTS
WHEN 762
THEN 70
when 767
THEN 70
when 768
THEN 70
WHEN 841
THEN 35
WHEN 842
then 35
else 0
end +
case LTRIM(RTRIM(LENS.COATTYP))   --ARC POINTS
when 'HVLL'
then 50
when 'HVLLBLUE'
then 100
else 0
end +
CASE LENS.LNS_IDX   --MATERIAL POINTS
when 53
THEN 35
WHEN 56
THEN 35
WHEN 58
then 35
when 61
then 35
else 0
END +
CASE LENS.LNS_MATCLR  --COLOR POINTS
WHEN 00
THEN 0
WHEN 46
THEN 35
WHEN 47
THEN 35
WHEN 48
then 35
else 0

end as TOTAL_POINTS)*lens.qty / 2

else

CASE LENS.LNS_PROGTYPE  --DESIGN pOINTS
WHEN 762
THEN 70
when 767
THEN 70
when 768
THEN 70
WHEN 841
THEN 35
WHEN 842
then 35
else 0
end +
case LTRIM(RTRIM(LENS.COATTYP))   --ARC POINTS
when 'HVLL'
then 50
when 'HVLLBLUE'
then 100
else 0
end +
CASE LENS.LNS_IDX   --MATERIAL POINTS
when 53
THEN 35
WHEN 56
THEN 35
WHEN 58
then 35
when 61
then 35
else 0
END +
CASE LENS.LNS_MATCLR  --COLOR POINTS
WHEN 00
THEN 0
WHEN 46
THEN 35
WHEN 47
THEN 35
WHEN 48
then 35
else 0

end as TOTAL_POINTS)
```

i keep getting syntax error and i am not sure where i am going wrong
i am not sure how to do it and to be honest i don't completely understand the examples i have viewed your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `IF` is a statement, that should enclose other statements. If you're wanting an expression, you should be using `CASE` throughout. Also, have you considered introducing tables that store all of these magical mapping values rather than building long `CASE` expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
(CASE
  WHEN LENS.LNS_PROGTYPE IN (762,767,768) THEN 70
  WHEN LENS.LNS_PROGTYPE IN (841,842) THEN 35
  else 0
end +
case LTRIM(RTRIM(LENS.COATTYP))   --ARC POINTS
  when 'HVLL'      then 50
  when 'HVLLBLUE'  then 100
  else 0
end +
CASE
  WHEN LENS.LNS_IDX IN (53,56,58,61) THEN 35
  else 0
END +
CASE
  WHEN LENS.LNS_MATCLR IN (46,47,48) THEN 35
  else 0
end) * CASE WHEN lens.qty > 1 THEN lens.qty / 2 ELSE 1 END
```

For the entire expression. But, as I said, I'd also introduce some mapping tables rather than having all of these magic constants in the `CASE` expressions.

Comment: HI thanks for all the replies. i used the script that Damien suggested and it works great but when my qty = 3 it does not do any calculation which i don't understand it does for 1,2,4,6, etc but for 3 nothing

Comment: @KallieReyneke - if everything is currently in `int`s, and you're wanting to have that multiply the calculation by 1.5, you need to force it to switch to `float`s. Something as simple as `lens.qty / 2.0` in the last line would be sufficient to force the switch.

Comment: thank you very much @damien_the_unbeliever that solved the problem.  is there any way to have only 2 zeros after the decimal , i will play around with cast and convert to see if that will fix the trailing zeros

Comment: hi i have played around with the cast and convert method but i am not able to get rid of the trailing zeros. this is below my code select LENS.QTY,
(case  convert(money ,LENS.LNS_MATCLR,0)  --COLOR POINTS
    when 40 then 35.00
    when 41 then 35.00
    when 48 THEN 35.00
    else 0
    end) * case when LENS.QTY > 1 then LENS.QTY / 2.0 else 1.0 end as TOTAL_POINTS
    FROM LENS WHERE QTY > 1 AND LENS.LNS_MATCLR in (40,41,48) it still gives output of 262.50000000 i have tried converting to int , money to no avail

Comment: Hi i got it working

please see below what i did


       (CASE   --TRANSISTIONS POINTS
        WHEN LENS.LNS_MATCLR in (40,41,48) THEN 35
        else 0
        end) * case when LENS.QTY > 1 then cast(cast(LENS.QTY as decimal(18,2))as float) / 2          else 1
        END AS TRANSISTIONS_POINTS,

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you must make sure, that all elements of that string/sum are of the same datatype. cast/convert them appropriately.